# Variable not updated after change in different controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, apply

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>

      <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">Ctrl1.option = {{option}}</div>

      <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">Crtl2.thisOtpion = {{thisOption}}</div>

    </div>

    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js" ng:autobind></script>
    <script>
      angular.module("App", []).controller("Ctrl1", function($scope) {
        $scope.option = 1;
      });

      angular.module("App").controller("Ctrl2",  ["$scope", "$controller",
        function($scope, $controller) {

              $scope.thisOption;

                var Ctrl1Proxy = $scope.$new();
            $controller("Ctrl1", {$scope : Ctrl1Proxy});
            Ctrl1Proxy.option = 0;
            $scope.thisOption = Ctrl1Proxy.option;



        }
      ]);

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

The result is: 1

Why isn't the variable option updated to 0? And what should I do to obtain this result? I already tried using $apply also in combination with $timeout. But without any success.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using rootScope?

Comment: I'm sorry, my question probably wasn't clear. I have changed the code to improve it. Controllers aren't nested in my original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this , If multiple controller you have to use $rootScope to share data OR Use [$broadcast](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

, if its nested Controller.Use `$scope.$parent.option = 0` instead of   `var Ctrl1Proxy = $scope.$new();`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>

      <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">Ctrl1.option = {{option}}</div>

      <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">Crtl2.thisOtpion = {{thisOption}}</div>

    </div>

    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js" ng:autobind></script>
    <script>
      angular.module("App", []).controller("Ctrl1", function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.option = 1;
      });

      angular.module("App").controller("Ctrl2",  ["$scope", "$controller","$rootScope",
        function($scope, $controller,$rootScope) {

              $scope.thisOption;

                var Ctrl1Proxy = $scope.$new();
            Ctrl1Proxy=$controller("Ctrl1", {$scope : Ctrl1Proxy});
            Ctrl1Proxy.option = 0;
            $scope.thisOption = Ctrl1Proxy.option;
            $rootScope.option = 0;
          
        }
      ]);

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, my question probably wasn't clear. I have changed the code to improve it. Controllers aren't nested in my original code.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should use `$rootScope`

### html

```
 <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">

      <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">{{option}}</div>

    </div>
```

### JavaScript

```
angular.module("App", []).controller("Ctrl1", function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.option = 1;
      });

      angular.module("App").controller("Ctrl2",  ["$scope", "$location", "$controller", "$timeout","$rootScope",
        function($scope, $location, $controller, $timeout,$rootScope) {
            // Forward if user is not a manager



                   $rootScope.option = 0;



        }
      ]);
```

[reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope)

Comment: I'm sorry, my question probably wasn't clear. I have changed the code to improve it. Controllers aren't nested in my original code.